# What does @Tag Annotation does

Tags: java, annotations

I am working on a project where the variables of classes have @Tag annotation above it. What is its function?

It looks like this

```
@Tag(10)
private GroupNavigationSRO groups;

@Tag(16)
private String redirectedQuery;

@Tag(17)
private GetGuidedSearchResponse guidedSearchResponse ;
```

I tried searching the internet but couldn't find any relevant answer

Comment: It's code, just like any other code in your file. If it's compiling, you're importing it somewhere. Look at your imports, and at the fully-qualified class name (e.g. `com.foo.Tag`). Try googling that, and/or looking at the Javadoc, if that's available. Without knowing which libraries your project is using, it could be a variety of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that this is the `io.protostuff.Tag` class defined by the "protostuff" library.  If so, then [this page](http://www.protostuff.io/documentation/runtime-schema/) explains that `@Tag(number)` is an explicit way of setting the field numbers in a serialization.